# Connecting to API works using Shell but w/ Python requests lib throws 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url

Tags: python, api, graphql

I'm trying to connect to the [Fluctuo](https://flow.fluctuo.com/api) (mobility data) GraphQL API with my access token. It works perfectly well using the curl Shell script, but it throws a `400 Client Error: Bad Request for url` when trying the same using the Python requests library.

This is the curl script that works:

```
curl --request POST \
      --url https://flow-api.fluctuo.com/v1?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN \
      --header 'content-type: application/json' \
      --data '{"query":"query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {\n  vehicles(lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {\n\t\tid\n  }\n}","variables":{"lat":48.856614,"lng":2.352222}}'
```

This is the Python code that throws the error:

```
url = "https://flow-api.fluctuo.com/v1?access_token=" + MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
head = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
query='''
query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {\n  vehicles(lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {\n\t\tid\n  }\n}","variables":{"lat":48.856614,"lng":2.352222}'''

try:
    r = requests.post(url, json={'query': query},headers=head)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)
```

Any ideas about what could go wrong is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the meantime: the POST data needed to be JSON-encoded. I dumped the query into JSON and this solved the issue. See code below.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://flow-api.fluctuo.com/v1?access_token=" + MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
head = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
data = {"query":"query ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {\n  vehicles(lat: $lat, lng: $lng) {\n\t\tid\n  }\n}","variables":{"lat":48.856614,"lng":2.352222}}

try:
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=head)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)

r.status_code
```